# How do I install ubuntu from windows?

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I have left 16GB unpartitioned for it. I imagine I would start the Installer from windows and it would create an initial bootable file system on my hard drive, then I would restart and boot it, and it finishes the install. I want to keep my windows too. Is this possible?

Comment: You start with installing Ubuntu on a bootable device like a USB/CD, then restart the computer and boot the USB/CD. Now just click on install along windows. And everything will be set up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go get Unetbootin, pendrive with at least 2 GB space and an Ubuntu iso of course. You have to start Unetbootin, browse to the iso, choose the right pendrive and start. After it's done, boot from USB and start installation. Remember to choose right partition. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not what you do. Instead you burn a bootable disk or usb stick using the "disk images" found on Ubuntu's website. You then boot your medium and follow the installer. Manual partitioning is also unnecessary, as the installer can create a partition for you.